# First item added to $_SESSION array is added TWICE...why?

Tags: php, arrays, session, cart

Yesterday I posted a question on SO [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541283/how-to-find-a-specific-value-in-multidimensional-session-array) regarding a multidimensional `$_SESSION` array I was working with to keep track of items in a shopping cart I'm developing. One of the very helpful responses suggested I create the `$_SESSION` array not as a multidimensional array, which I agree is a smoother approach.

The `$_SESSION` array is started when a user clicks any of the 'Add to Cart' buttons on the store page. My original code with the multidimensional array is this:

```
$quantity = 1;

// add first item from shop page
if(isset($_POST['add_item']) && (!isset($_SESSION['cart']))) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
    $_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['product_description']] = array('quantity' => $quantity, 'price' => $_POST['product_price']);
    header("Location: http://website.com/cart.php");
    }
```

And this worked fine, but I was not able to achieve the results with this that I wanted (see the other post).

The code I was suggested to use is this:

```
$quantity = 1;

// add first item from shop page
if(isset($_POST['add_item']) && (!isset($_SESSION['cart']))) {
$_SESSION['cart'][] = array('product_description'=> $_POST['product_description'], 'quantity' => $quantity, 'price' => $_POST['product_price']);
header("Location: http://website.com/cart.php");
}
```

And it works great and allows me to do what I want to do (again, see the other post for details).

HOWEVER...

Regardless of which 'Add to Cart' button is clicked on the store page (there are only four), the FIRST click gets information added to the `$_SESSION['cart']` array TWICE. Every other button clicked afterward is entered only once. And again, it does not matter which button is clicked first, this happens no matter what.

Here's the result of a `print_r` on the new `$_SESSION` array code:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_description] => iPhone case - Black
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 9.49
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        [product_description] => iPhone case - Black
        [quantity] => 1
        [price] => 9.49
    )

)
```

I have scoured SO and Google for clues as to why this is happening, but no matter how I word my queries, I just can't seem to find anything that helps.

It has to be something simple that I am missing...

Sincere thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

To clarify, there are only 4 items on the store page. There won't ever be any more. To keep things super simple, each item has its own 'Add to Cart' button. When the button is clicked, the user is taken to the cart page where they can adjust the quantity or delete the item then either check out cancel and clear the cart or continue shopping.

Comment: Can you post your full shop page, and is the shop form self submitting (meaning, is the code that adds the item to the cart at the top of the shop page, or in another file)?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. The buttons on the shop page are coded into the page and the user clicks one and we get the results mentioned above. It's important to note that this wasn't happening with the convoluted multidimensional code I show in the other post. It was ONLY the rewritten `$_SESSION` code that I changed. NOTHING else. That's what is so weird.

Comment: can a user only add one item to the cart by design? The code above will only add an item if the $_SESSION['cart'] isn't set.

Comment: If you only need to have one item in the cart, then you can change $_SESSION['cart'][] = ..... to $_SESSION['cart'] = .... (remove the empty braces). Also, you should probably have an exit; call after your location header to prevent the page from processing anything else.

Comment: Yes, you probably have code after that condition that adds the item again. After the first time, the $_SESSION['cart'] is set so subsequent items will only be added once.

Comment: hmm, As a side node: DON'T (!!) pass the price using POST - fetch it from the database - or i'll `POST` some data to your side, putting iPhones for $0.99 to my cart :-)

Comment: The single item is added to begin with then the quantity can be changed in the cart. The thing to remember is, with my shoddy multidimensional array, this all worked fine. It was only until I changed to the single dimensional array that things went bonkers. and, it's the ONLY line of code I changed! This is so weird.

Comment: I don't have any code that adds the condition again. Promise.

Comment: I understand the comment about altering the price hidden variable, thank you. There are only 4 items in the store so the thought of using a DB to handle this seemed overkill. I'll add the price in the cart instead Many thanks!

Comment: This is still a multidimensional array (the cart array holds product arrays). The reason why your old code wouldn't have done this is because your older code used the name of the product as the array key in the cart array, so even if you added 50 'iPhone case - Black' products, each one would have updated the first as each one was added, and you would have been left with just one in the cart array. Without being able to see the rest of the code, we can't help you find where the item is being duplicated. Would you be willing to hop on skype and share the code privately (php coding is my job)?

Comment: @mmoul You are absolutely correct about the multidimensional array. Should I go back to my original code instead?

Comment: You can, but you'll need to change your foreach when looping through the cart array to foreach($_SESSION['cart'], $key => $val) and then check the $key for the product description and if you find one you want, you the access the items in the $val array. Again though, there is an issue somewhere in your code adding the product twice.

Answer (score 0):

Your description seems to say you want something like:

- check to see the cart exists, create if it doesn't
- then add the item to the cart

The code you posted seems to only add an item, if you don't have a cart yet.

The only reason I can think of for the double item though is that there is more code than you posted and you have the code for the "add item" bit happening in both the "create cart" and a later "add item" chunk.

Here's what I would do:

```
quantity = 1;

// ensure cart
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

// add item from shop page
if(isset($_POST['add_item'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['product_description']] = array(
        'quantity' => $quantity, 
        'price' => $_POST['product_price']
    );

    // or if you prefer the numeric indexed array:
    // $_SESSION['cart'][] = array(
    //     'product_description'=> $_POST['product_description'], 
    //     'quantity' => $quantity, 
    //     'price' => $_POST['product_price']);

    header("Location: http://website.com/cart.php");
}
```

I've modified your code in place to keep the logic simple, but like @dognose comments: do not trust the prices passed via the post. It is far to simple to hack a form and post you bad data to get your stuff for $0.01 like that.

Comment: Thank you for that, very well put. I'm going to give this a try. I didn't want to create the cart session until the first item was chosen.

Comment: If it solves your problem, mark it as the solution. But seriously seriously seriously - do NOT trust form-posted prices. A better option would be to have code that looks up your description (or a numeric ID) and gets the price in the server code (the other comments suggest a database lookup, but you could have a simple array in your code that does the matching too - DO NOT TRUST POSTED INPUT!)

Comment: Thank you, I understand completely about the posted form prices. I'm changing this as we speak. I'm also testing the code right now and will let you know if this solves my problem.

Comment: Okay, this works fine, actually, it's exactly how I was doing it to start with. I changed the assignment of the price variable using a DB so we're good there. What got me in this mess to begin with is, how to search the `$_SESSION['cart']` array for a specific product description such as "iPhone Case - Black"?

Comment: foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $cart_item) { if ($cart_item['product_description'] == 'whatever') { ... } }

Comment: Or if you just want to grab the record... you could use array_filter passing a function, or just put the desc as the key like you did originally.

Comment: The problem with placing the description as key was that the initial value was being added TWICE to the array, hence this thread.

Comment: setting the description as the key actually would prevent multiple instances in your array since keys must be unique.

Comment: Don't know what to tell ya, but it did add whichever item was initially selected TWICE. Each item afterward was entered only once.

Comment: Without seeing the whole file that was causing the dupes, it's hard to guess why, other than there were two places it was getting added, like (when you create the cart) and (when the cart already exists)... "if (no cart) then (create cart add item); if (cart) then (add item);" where the second part is always true because the first part already ran. (Hint: should have not added the item in the first if block)

Comment: Interesting idea, but I removed all other `if` blocks when I was having this problem last night and the problem still persisted.

Answer (score -2):

Cannot answer as the full code is not provided; However:

```
$_SESSION = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $_SESSION)));
```

will remove the duplicates from your session.